# Applying custom layout to ActionBar in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I'm trying to change the layout of the actionBar in my app. I managed to display the layout, but there's a problem - the layout doesn't stretch to entire width of the bar and I don't see the title and the icon. Here's how I see it right now:

[image]

This is the XML of my custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/app_bg"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is how I tried to display it in my main FragmentActivity, along with the title:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setSubtitle("welcome to my app");
    actionBar.setTitle("My App"); 
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

I want the layout to stretch to entire width of the bar. Also, I'd like to have the options button on the right of the menu later (to the left of the button).

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do? It looks like you're trying to change the background of the Action Bar and add a custom button. Is that all? Please better explain or illustrate the desired result.

Comment: @PaulBurke At the moment I want to achieve the following: change the background, have the Options menu on the left (the 3 vertical dots button), and next to it another action icon/button, which should change accordingly to the tab I open and have different actions in different tabs. I'd also like to change the font and the color of the title, to match the design of my app and, possibly, add a subtitle (unless I have to use actionBarSherlock for that, then I don't mind to omit it).